# Stripping excess 0's from multiple seperate values in single string in python when performing calculation

Tags: python

This is a small piece of code mirroring the trouble area in my program.

```
templine = '1 + 100 + 001 + 1.01 + 1.00'
calcline = eval(templine)
```

All of these values were individually entered into a tkinter entry box and then set to templine using the `.get()` command. These values will change depending on user input and calculations will then be performed. The calcline mirrors the equal button function using similar code.

I wanted to add a line in the middle to strip all unnecessary `'0'` from the code in this example I would like the `1 + 100 + 001 + 1.01 + 1.00` to be returned as `1 + 100 + 1 + 1.01 + 1`. Since the `eval()` function does not perform maths whith excess `'0'`'s in front of the integers.

I have tried using things such as the `.replace()` , `.strip()`, `.rstrip` and `.lstrip`. The main problems with these are that they do not work on any values after the very beginning. Most likely due to the fact that my equation is stored as a string. Converting the equation string to a list performing the stripping and then converting it back may work but then the question arises of knowing when opperand/opperator ends/begins.
Please help if this is solvable.

Comment: This sounds unnecessary, why are you ending up with this string? Does the user input an equation? You say they were entered separately, doesn't this mean we can operate on each value separately?

Comment: @Goldwave It's then stored in a tkinter entry box. Also I wasn't realy clear on how they were input but they're input individually similarly to a calculator and each character is stored as a different value which has the same problem of determining where one number begins and ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could break it up, strip the zeros and recombine it into a string again.

```
' + '.join(map(str, map(float,templine.split('+'))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the variables are accessible separately, as you say. It is an easy task.

```
print(float('1.01000'))
```

outputs

```
1.01
```

All you have to do, is to repeat this for each variable. Then combine them into the equation.